# How to format string currency c#

Tags: c#, string

How can I format a string number to be the following

```
12 -> $12.00 USD
12.1 -> $12.10 USD
12.11 -> $12.11 USD
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `string.Format` e.g.

```
public string GetCurrency(double amount)
{
    return string.Format("{0:C} USD", amount );
}
```

Output

$12.11 USD

Answer (score 1):

Use [`String.Format`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with the [currency format specifier `C`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s8s7t687.aspx):

`String.Format("{0:C} USD", 12);`